# How to synchronize some counters all increasing at the same rate and ending at different values

Tags: javascript, html, dom, time

I have 4 `span` elements inside an HTML document starting at 0, and i want to increase their value by 1 till they arrive at a marked value.

They all should end at the same time even with different values.

This is the function that i'm using, the **item** param is the `span` and the **number** is the number where i want to stop increasing the value.

```
let animateNumberInItem = (number,item) =>{
  let startingNum = 0;
  let animationSpeed = 0;

  
  let interval = setInterval(()=>{
    if(startingNum === number-1){
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
    startingNum++;
    item.innerHTML = startingNum;
  },animationSpeed);
};
```

Any idea on how to calculate the time required to reach the number in milliseconds using the **number** value?

Another solution could be changing the number by which they increase or/and the time to make them end at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

If you increase the `startingNum` based on the ratio in which target numbers are present, then they will reach the target at the same time.

```js
let animateNumberInItem = (number,item, ratio) =>{
  let startingNum = 0;
  let animationSpeed = 30;
  
  let interval = setInterval(()=>{
    if(startingNum >= number){
      clearInterval(interval);
    } else {
      // Increase the startingNum based on the ratio in which target number is present
       startingNum += ratio;
      item.innerHTML = Math.round(startingNum);
    }
   
  },animationSpeed);
};

// e.g. first element has to reach target of 201 and second element has to reach target of 100
const ratio = 100/201;
animateNumberInItem(201, document.getElementById('first'), 1);
animateNumberInItem(100, document.getElementById('second'), ratio);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <span id="first">0</span>
  <span id="second">0</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not what i'm asking for, i want to find a numerical value of time for each counter to make them reach their top value at the same time, not know the execution time.

Comment: @Gabri Ratio of the target numbers should be used so that each of them reach their top value at the same time. I have modified the answer.

Comment: Your answer is just a copy of mine by the way

Comment: @Gabri yes. Only difference is by how much `startingNum` has to be increased. I thought the ratio between between numbers can be used to control the amount by which `startingNum`  is incremented. Anyway, if adding an arbitrary `animationGrowNumber ` solves your problem, then it is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution and it's easier than it seems.

This is the edited function:

```
let animateNumberInItem = (number,item) =>{
  let startingNum = 0;
  let animationSpeed = 30;
  let animationGrowNumber = number / 100;
  
  let interval = setInterval(()=>{
    if(startingNum >= number- animationGrowNumber){
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
    startingNum+=animationGrowNumber;
    item.innerHTML = Math.round(startingNum);
  },animationSpeed);
};
```

You just need to divide the number between a value (i used 100 because it gives a smoother animation) and then set that as the increasing value.

It will not increase by 1 but the animation looks good anyways, you can also set the time that you want because it doesn't affect the end result, only the animation appearence.

Comment: In above function, adding `animationGrowNumber` will require special case handling at the upper boundary condition. for e.g. `animateNumberInItem(201, item);` will take the target counter to `203`  which is not correct.

Comment: The upper boundary overflow is safeguarded just under the setInterval method, it works fine.